# Can Vuforia work alongside ARFoundation 5.0 in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia, ar-foundation

I can't get Vuforia and ARFoundation 5.0 to work together for Android in Unity. In a basic scene with no code, using only Vuforia, the Image Targets recognition works perfectly. When this same basic scene is under ARFoundation 5.0, in play mode in the editor, the scene works correctly and Vuforia's Image Targets work correctly. However, when I run it on an Android device, Vuforia doesn't recognize the target.

Is Vuforia compatible with the new ARFoundation 5.0?

These error messages from Vuforia appear in logcat when I use the ARFoundation 5.0 scene:

```
Error Unity Exception in callback: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Error Unity Vuforia.Utility.ExtensionMethods.DelegateHelper:InvokeDelegate(Delegate, Object[])
Error Unity Vuforia.Internal.Core.Engine:OnStart()
Error Unity Vuforia.Internal.Core.Engine:Start(Action)
Error Unity System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo)
Error Unity System.Delegate:DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[])
Error Unity Vuforia.Utility.ExtensionMethods.DelegateHelper:InvokeDelegate(Delegate, Object[])
Error Unity Vuforia.Utility.ExtensionMethods.DelegateHelper:InvokeWithExceptionHandling(Action`1, T)
Error Unity Vuforia.Internal.Core.Engine:InitOnCameraReady()
Error Unity Vuforia.Internal.ARFoundation.<CheckAvailability>d__20:MoveNext()
Error Unity UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
```

Update - There's a bug in Vuforia with AR Foundation 5.x. There's a temporary solution until a new release is available:

On the XR Origin GameObject, replace the XR Origin Component with an AR Session Origin (ignore the deprecation message)
In the new component, set the Camera Offset GameObject as the Camera Floor Offset Object, the Main Camera as the Camera GameObject , and the Tracking Origin Mode to Device.

https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues/15

Comment: I would file an issue here https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it seems like the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this workaround:

- On the XR Origin GameObject, replace the XR Origin Component with an AR Session Origin (ignore the deprecation message)
- In the new component, set the Camera Offset GameObject as the Camera Floor Offset Object, the Main Camera as the Camera GameObject, and the Tracking Origin Mode to Device

Release version with fix will be provided [here](https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues/15).